# Convert csv coloumn data and output

Tags: csv, forms

I have been given a hefty excel file containing a column of 'old' numbers and a column of 'new' numbers next to it.

I have exported this as a csv file

I need to create a html form which will allow the user to input their old number so that it will display the new number.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show some rows from csv, and expected html output sample.

Comment: well, you need to get out there, face the warm morning sunlight,breathe in the fresh air and say to yourself - i'll start with it now.

Comment: what programing language are u using can u provide some code please show us what u did so far ?

Comment: For instance...
15129 needs converting to 11680
15130 needs converting to 11691

Its a number converter - I'm open to suggestions on the best way of doing this as i haven't started yet

Similar to this...[link]http://jsfiddle.net/yHhz9/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NsLXt/

Comment: that's an excellent start thank you so much! - now just to complicate things...what about if there was a third and fourth column? - i.e. you input the old number - you get the new number underneath that you get the data from the third coloumn i.e. name, underneath that you get a city - thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/NsLXt/2/

html

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="old-number" placeholder="old number" />
    <button id="convert">convert</button>
    <input type="text" id="new-number" placeholder="new number" readonly />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name" readonly />
    <input type="text" id="city" placeholder="city" readonly />
</div>
```

coffeescript

```
conversion =
    15128:
        number: 11599
        name: 'name-of-11599'
        city: 'city-of-11599'
    15129:
        number: 11680
        name: 'name-of-11680'
        city: 'city-of-11680'
    15130:
        number: 11691
        name: 'name-of-11691'
        city: 'city-of-11691'
    15132:
        number: 11694
        name: 'name-of-11694'
        city: 'city-of-11694'
    10097:
        number: 14051
        name: 'name-of-14051'
        city: 'city-of-14051'
    10022:
        number: 14094
        name: 'name-of-14094'
        city: 'city-of-14094'

convert = ->
    old_number = $('#old-number').val()
    new_data = conversion[old_number]
    if new_data
        $('#new-number').val(new_data.number)
        $('#name').val(new_data.name)
        $('#city').val(new_data.city)
    else
        $('#new-number').val('Not found')
        $('#name').val('')
        $('#city').val('')

$('#convert').click(convert)
$('#old-number').keydown (e) ->
    if e.which == 13
        convert()
```